# How do I change MonoDevelop Target Framework to iPhone for imported .Net library project

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've imported an existing C# library project into a MonoDevelop Solution targeted for iPhone.  My original project has a target Framework selection of Mono for iPhone but my newly added project only has Mono/.Net choices.  How do I get the iphone targets to show up so I can properly reference it from my existing iPhone targeted projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way I've found is to make a new MonoTouch Library project and either "link" or "copy" the files from the existing project.

This is usually necessary anyway, as usually you will have to add `#if MONOTOUCH` preprocessor statements in a couple places.

Comment: So what you're saying is you can't share project files between visual studio x86 and monodevelop for an iPhone target?

Comment: Nope.  You probably will have some code that will differ anyway.  Make sure you know how to "link" files, you won't have 2 copies of each file if you set it up properly.

Comment: OK, I created a sibling csproj with a different name in the same directory.